# What are some legal concerns I should have before consulting a web developer on an idea of mine

Tags: legal

I have an idea for a web application but I am a little bit hesitant to consult a company due to fears of having my idea stolen.

What are some preliminary tasks I should set myself before actually consulting a company representative?

My main concerns are strictly legal-related. What measures should I take to make sure that the company does not steal any of my ideas with regards to the application's features, design, name, etc.

Comment: Patent it, done.

Comment: Even if your idea is brilliant it is only [worth $20](https://crew.co/how-to-build-an-online-business/idea-vs-execution/). Anything you have designed or named will be covered under copyright, depending on your country you probably don't even need to register anything for your creations. I wouldn't worry too much about anyone stealing your ideas.

Comment: @Bálint most game ideas are not patentable. Also, software patents are invalid in many jurisdictions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general legal issues; consider looking into the Law SE.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be afraid that your game idea gets stolen, because game ideas just by themselves are worthless.

1. Nobody can tell if an idea is good without seeing it implemented in a game. There are lots of ideas which sound really great in your head. Some of them might even still sound great to someone else when you describe them. But when someone tries to implement them, it turns out they aren't actually fun or are infeasible to implement ([*cough*](http://store.steampowered.com/app/275850/#app_reviews_hash)). People in the game industry know that, so before you have a playable prototype which demonstrates your idea is worth stealing, nobody will steal it.
2. Sharing your idea helps you refine it. People will tell you their opinion, what they think won't work, and what would be cool to add to it. The earlier you can get feedback the better.
3. Everyone in the game industry has their head full of ideas and would rather work on their own ideas than those of someone else. So they aren't even interested in stealing your ideas.
4. Even if someone steals your idea and beats you to market, that's actually good for you. No game idea goes to market fully developed. You can look at that game and observe how your idea works out in practice. You can see what works and what doesn't, what mistakes they made and what useful additions they added. You can learn from them and use that experience to create an even better implementation of your idea. When you are finished, the players of the first game will be bored by it and will be looking for a new game to play which is similar but better: Yours!

But if you want to protect your idea nevertheless, you can have your prospective business partners sign a [non-disclosure agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement). How to write legal texts is out of the scope of this website, so you might want to ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com) for details. Keep in mind that forcing people to sign a paper which might get them sued one day will drive some people away.